# Display all products of a product type in Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

Right now, I have to add each product one by one. Is there a way to display all the products of a particular product type all at once? Like when using a view to display all the nodes tagged with a certain taxonomy term?
The products have already been created, and just need to be attached to their respective displays.

Comment: You can use views for the same...

Comment: I understand that using views in the way I described will achieve the desired effect, but then does this mean the method of creating product displays as a content type is moot for my use case? Since the product itself is a multi-value field in the product display content type?

Comment: The view should bring all the product display nodes, and then have a relationship to the product entity itself and then finally add a filter using that relationship to filter by the product type. Is that what you need?

Comment: After another round of googling, I came across [Adding products](https://drupal.org/node/1051966) and the first comment by David D sums it up nicely. In his words, "This 2-step Product > Product Display node process is presented as being essential in Drupal Commerce, but I don't believe it actually is, if your products have no options."